# What tool can I use to create an HTML5 candlestick chart with an inverted axis?

Tags: javascript, html, charts, data-visualization, visualization

Google's charting API supports a [candlestick chart](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/candlestickchart) with the ability to change the values on the X axis - i.e. they are week days here but could be other things.

However, as far as I can tell, this charting API does not allow you to change the line width for the "wicks", and it is impossible to invert the axis so that 0 is on top (unless you switch to using all negative values).

Highcharts has a more [full featured candlestick chart](https://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/candlestick/gray) and the ability to reverse the y axis, but as far as I can tell you MUST use timestamps as values for the x axis.

What tool can I use to create an HTML5 candlestick chart with an inverted Y axis and the ability to set custom labels on the X axis, and possibly and option to adjust the "wick" thickness?

#### Google Chart Example

[image]

#### Highcharts Example

[image: Picture 1.png]

#### jqChart Example

(this is pretty messed up - source here http://jsfiddle.net/FSEQP/ )

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div id="jqChart" style="width: 800px; height: 550px;" />
    
</body>
</html>
```

```
        function round(d) {
            return Math.round(100 * d) / 100;
        }

        var data = [];

        var date = new Date(2010, 0, 1);

        var high = Math.random() * 40;
        var close = high - Math.random();
        var low = close - Math.random();
        var open = (high - low) * Math.random() + low;

        data.push([date, round(high), round(low), round(open), round(close)]);

        for (var day = 2; day <= 12; day++) {

            date = new Date(2010, 0, day);

            high = open + Math.random();

            close = high - Math.random();
            low = close - Math.random();
            var oldOpen = open;
            open = (high - low) * Math.random() + low;

            if (low > oldOpen) {
                low = oldOpen;
            }

            data.push([date, round(high), round(low), round(open), round(close)]);
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#jqChart').jqChart({
                title: { text: 'Candlestick Chart' },
                legend: { visible: false },

//                                labelsOptions : { visible: false },



                          axes: [

                                {
                                    type: 'linear',
                                    location: 'left',
                                    reversed: true
                                },
                                  {
                                      type: 'category',
                                      location: 'bottom',
                                                        categories: [
                                                        'Category 1', 'Category 2', 'Category 3',
                                                        'Category 4', 'Category 5', 'Category 6',
                                                        'Category 7', 'Category 8', 'Category 9',
                                                        'Category 10', 'Category 11', 'Category 12'
                                                        ],
                                      labels: {
                                                  font: '12px sans-serif',
                                                  angle: -90,

                                               }
                                  }
                               ],



                series: [
                            {
                                type: 'column',
                                data: data
                            }
                        ]
            });







        });
```

[image: Picture.png]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe [jqChart](http://www.jqchart.com/) fits your requirements.

- [Candlestick Chart Sample](http://www.jqchart.com/samples/FinancialCharts/CandlestickChartWithVolume); [Documentation](http://www.jqchart.com/documentation/userguide/default.aspx#!CandlestickCharts)
- [Inverted (Reversed) Axis Scale](http://www.jqchart.com/SamplesAspNetMVC/ChartAxes/ReversedScale)

Comment: I don't see a way to change the X axis labels with jqCharts but it looks good otherwise

Comment: The axis labels can be formatted : http://www.jqchart.com/documentation/userguide/default.aspx#!AxisElements   http://www.jqchart.com/documentation/userguide/default.aspx#!LabelsFormatting

Comment: Documentation is not very helpful. I can't figure out how to replace the labels at the bottom. I can add "category groups" on top of the labels, but that's not what i want.

Comment: Does the last sample from this link http://www.jqchart.com/documentation/userguide/default.aspx#!LabelsFormatting help? They can be formatted with - labels: { stringFormat: 'mmmm d, yyyy'. You can specify custom format here.

Comment: Here's what I've got so far. http://jsfiddle.net/FSEQP/

Comment: Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/FSEQP/1/

Comment: sweet! thanks! (also switched it back to candlestick - http://jsfiddle.net/FSEQP/2/)  now if I can just get the "wicks" to be wider

Comment: It is "lineWidth" option of the chart - http://jsfiddle.net/FSEQP/4/ . Unfortunately, we there is a little issue with the candles when the scale is reversed. The lines shouldn't cross the rectangles. We'll fix this asap.

Comment: this answer seriously needs to get updated ;), looks and feels kinda oldskool compared to the other suggestions on this page.

Comment: JQCharts uses a canvas to draw candles whereas highcharts uses svg to do the same, does this impact the performance in any way

Answer (score 10):

As pointed out in the comments by @PirateApp and @ivanxuu, `techan.js` is no longer maintained and there is now https://d3fc.io/

Besides there are currently (May 2020) active projects:

- https://plot.ly/javascript/candlestick-charts/ using `plotly.js` based on `d3.js`
- https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/#chart-type-candlestick
- http://dygraphs.com/

---

Original answer:

I recommend `techan.js` based on and by the author of D3js. It's free, open source and interactive.

https://github.com/andredumas/techan.js

http://techanjs.org/

Comment: Not maintained anymore

Comment: As is not mantained anymore, maybe you can consider [d3fc](https://d3fc.io/) as a replacement, which is a project that acknowledges techanjs as an influence.

Answer (score 0):

Try amCharts.com - their serial chart can accept strings for categoryAxis, valueAxes can be reversed and line thickness can also be adjusted. Here is example of candlestick chart: http://amcharts.com/javascript/candlestick-chart/

Comment: Where would I find the documentation on changing those things?

Comment: The new docs are here: http://docs.amcharts.com/3/

Comment: amCharts seems quite expensive, so they'd have to be really good?

Answer (score -4):

I'd suggest SVG to create such diagrams.

Comment: If you could provide an example or some links I would give you an upvote.